# Как решить проблему с переводом элементов с табов на аккордеон при ресайзе окна?

Tags: javascript

Суть вопроса в том, что есть элементы на странице. Дизайнер извращенец сделал их так,что на лэптопе они просто карточками, на таблетке они табами, а на мобайле они уже аккордеоном должны сделать. По идее сверстать это все получилось и по идее в `js` тоже вроде все работает и написано норм.на разных экранах и и так как надо. Проблема только в одном, если не перезагружать страницу и ресайзить окно, то как только элементы должны менять свое представление(становиться аккордеоном например), то все перестает работать до тех пор, пока страницу не перезагрузишь..Подскажите плиз, как решить этот вопрос?
И еще сразу из этого есть еще вопрос - а как возможно через `js` связать элементы на разных страницах?вот например эти услуги на главной странице в таком виде в каком они и есть(карточка, таб, аккордеон). И есть еще страница "услуг", на ней услуги представлены в том же виде, но чуть более подробное описание. Так вот как сделать, чтобы по клику на главной странице на "подробнее" на определенной услуге, был переход на страницу услуг и при этом на ней было открыто подробное описание именно той услуги, которую выбрал пользователь на главной?Это возможно сделать через js? если да, то как?
Вот пример как это выглядит https://jsfiddle.net/nyz2ko0w/

Comment: по второму вопросу - можно передать параметром в GET query и потом JS-ом оттуда прочитать его и раскрыть соответствующий значению параметра раздел на странице

Comment: а пример кода не сможешь показать?не совсем знаком с  этой темой? И по первому вопросу нет мыслей?